# Why was my flag for a link-only answer from 2008, declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I know it's [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/183757) but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218054/821057) of his posted in 2008 is link only.

My flag to this post get rejected by moderator as

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support

So any reason why is this a valid post?

Comment: What type of flag did you use?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I think I have used `needs moderator attention`.

Comment: While the guidelines partly seem somewhat fuzzy, my interpretation is that moderator attention flags should generally be used for relatively serious issues that potentially need more action than just deleting the post. For example, I use them in cases where I see a pattern (e.g. somebody going on a spamming spree) that probably needs to be stopped to prevent more damage. For plain link-only answer, a Very Low Quality or Not An Answer flag should be sufficient.

Comment: And take into account that he's got 30.000 answers! That's a lot of answers to track, he'll not remember every single one he ever wrote. Post a comment on it (you already did) to draw his attention to that one and ask him to update.

Comment: It is this kind of nagging that makes it such a pita to post answers at SO.  There's no upper limit on how long I have to maintain them, everybody thinks it should be my job.  When choosing how to answer a question today, I'm considering if I want to support it for the rest of my life and often end up posting a comment instead.

Comment: @HansPassant what other types of answers that were once allowed are now not allowed? Granted I only have a handful of answers compared to yours, but I hardly ever need to go back once an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 7):

I can't say that, as a moderator, I would be inclined to delete an answer that was posted six years ago having 16 upvotes, at a time when answers like this were more acceptable to the community, especially since the two articles he linked not only seem on-topic and very informative, but have actually survived six years without the links breaking.

Comment: The meta effect rears its head. The answer has accrued a downvote. I'm sure Jon must be crushed.

Comment: I swear! thats not me :)

Comment: @Robert So is there any documented rules How old and how much upvoted should not be flagged?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Not to pick on you, but Jon is incredibly active on the site... still.  Why not post a quick comment to him asking if he could expand on the links in the event they are ever unavailable?  Moderators should only be involved in things that the community can't handle themselves, so why did we need to get involved here?

Comment: -1 what does it matter that the answer is 6 years old? Do people no longer visit the question? SO is a living repository of information, we should not discriminate posts based on age.

Comment: @bluefeet you probably would be interested to take a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application/218054#comment41819900_218054): "This answer is over 6 years old, and the other answers already cover it. I don't think there's much to be gained from expanding this now."