# How to flag very old link-only answers

Tags: support

Reading [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275464/why-was-my-flag-for-a-link-only-answer-from-2008-declined) reminded me of a flagging-related question I've been meaning to ask. I wouldn't be surprised if it was asked before, but I can't find a dupe.

Normally if I saw a link-only answer I would flag it as very low quality. Please tell me if that is the incorrect action, maybe I'm wrong about it. But when you try to flag some old answers there is no option for very low quality. You get spam, offensive, not an answer, and moderator attention.

I'm not sure that link-only answers constitute "not an answer" unless the links are broken. And I'm hesitant to flag for moderator attention because I know the mods are busy. I have done this in the past and gotten declined, then gone back and flagged again as not an answer and had it accepted.

Is that the "official" correct course of action on these? Why is there no very low quality option?

Comment: I flag link-only answers *old or new* as "not an answer". See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: like you flag new ones?

Comment: Like @Louis, I flag 'em as 'not an answer'. I've got a few old answers deleted that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should old, high-rep, link-only, accepted answers be deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted)

Comment: @sphanley I didn't ask if they should be deleted, I asked *how* they should be deleted :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has nothing to do with how old a post is.  You cannot flag a post with a positive score as VLQ.  You should not be flagging such a post for moderator attention either.  They'll generally just decline the flag as it's a problem that users can handle without moderator intervention.

If an answer doesn't answer the question, instead only linking to a location where the answer can be found, then it is [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381) and can be flagged accordingly.

Comment: "There's really only _one_ valid exception to this rule, and that's when the _question_ is:

_Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick_" ([castle guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381))

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about the positive score. I guess usually when I flag answers they are both new and egregiously bad so don't have upvotes, so I correlated the missing option with older answers.

Comment: @gnat Such a question is offtopic and should be closed, not answered, so no, those answers aren't acceptable answers on SO.

Comment: @Servy that's irrelevant here, because here the question is about what to do with answers to such question that are _already_ there. and note, this is the quote from the very guidance you refer in the answer

Comment: @gnat That's effectively just saying don't waste your time deleting answers, delete the whole question and take the answers along with it.  The answers aren't acceptable, and shouldn't be kept around, it's just that deleting the whole question is the more time efficient way of getting rid of them.

Comment: per my reading, that's effectively just saying that moderators are free to decline not an answer flags in cases like that. Meaning your advice "can be flagged accordingly" is somewhat incomplete

Comment: @gnat Moderators don't handle those flags.

Comment: @Servy [they certainly do in some cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/165773) - eg when post was already in LQ queue before, or when answer is accepted. Also this can happen when moderator decides to simply walk over LQ queue

Comment: @gnat Yes in very rare cases a moderator can see them, but they rarely do; the design of the flag is for non-moderators to handle them.  The answers also should be deleted if flagged, it's just an inefficient use of your time to flag the answers instead of the question, it's not like the answers shouldn't be deleted.  Why are you so concerned about content that is clearly deletion-worthy?

Comment: I am concerned that misleading flaggers about tools at their disposal makes it harder to delete such a content